# A simple limit (x,y) question involving rationalization

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,0)} {\sqrt{2x-y}-2\over 2x-y-4}$$

I thought about rationalizing the numerator in some fashion, but I don't know what factor to multiply it with.

Comment: Expanding by √+2x−y+2  does not yield a clean result either. Apparently the answer is 1/4 however.

Comment: @user3832863 it does...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(x,y) \rightarrow (2,0)$ you can consider $2x-y$ positive and then $$2x-y-4=(\sqrt{2x-y}-2)(\sqrt{2x-y}+2) $$ Your limit is just $lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (2,0)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-y}+2}=1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Expand by $\sqrt{2x-y}+2\over\sqrt{2x-y}+2 $:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,0)} {\sqrt{2x-y}-2\over 2x-y-4} =\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,0)} {\left(\sqrt{2x-y}-2\right)\left(\sqrt{2x-y}+2\right)\over \left(2x-y-4\right)\left(\sqrt{2x-y}+2\right)}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,0)} {2x-y-4\over \left(2x-y-4\right)\left(\sqrt{2x-y}+2\right)} =\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,0)} {1\over \sqrt{2x-y}+2}={1\over \sqrt{2\cdot2-0}+2}  = {1\over 4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the numerator is $\sqrt{2x-y}-2$, the most obvious way to rationalise it is to expand by $\sqrt{2x-y}+2$, so that the square root is squared and therefore disappear.

Comment: After doing this, the square root is in the denominator, and the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: @user3832862 True. Completely removing the square root sign is impossible. However, you are now capable of massively simplifying the fraction, since what you get is $$\frac{2x-y-4}{(2x-y-4)(\sqrt{2x-y}+2)}$$Generally speaking, $\sqrt{2x-y}+2$ is easier to handle no matter where in the fraction it appears, since it doesn't evaluate to $0$ when you go to the limit.